# Toggle next element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a problem with the `this` element (I know how `this` is working).

I have a lot of that html structure. When I click on the a button, the div with class `extra-options` must be shown. But since I have a lot of the same html structure repeated throughout, when I click on the button, all the other div options are also shown.

How can I fix it?

Here’s the JavaScript:

```
var buttonSubmit = $(".extra-options .details a.button");
    buttonSubmit.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var extraOptions = $(".extra-options-tickets");

        if($(".extra-options-tickets").is(":visible")) {
            extraOptions.hide();
        } else {
            extraOptions.fadeIn(450);
        };

    });
```

And here’s the  html:

```
<p class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="button" title="Toevoegen"><span>Toevoegen</span></a>
</p>
<div class="extra-options-tickets" style="display: none; ">text</div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do some *DOM traversing* to find the right element: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/. You said you have a problem with `this` but I don't even see you using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code so that you get the extra options div directly after the clicked link like this:

```
buttonSubmit.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the extra options directly after the clicked link
    var extraOptions = $(this).closest('p.actions').next('div.extra-options-tickets');

    if(extraOptions.is(":visible")) {
        extraOptions.hide();
    } else {
        extraOptions.fadeIn(450);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You should use `jQuery.parent()` and `jQuery.next()` to get this done.
Check out the sample and this [jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ez9qh/).

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<p class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="button" title="Toevoegen"><span>Toevoegen</span></a>
</p>
<div class="extra-options-tickets" style="display: none; ">
text
</div>

<p class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="button" title="Toevoegen"><span>Toevoegen</span></a>
</p>
<div class="extra-options-tickets" style="display: none; ">
text
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var div = $(this).parent().next();
    if(div.is(":visible")) {
        div.hide();
    } else {
        div.fadeIn(450);
    };
});
```

#### More Information

- **[jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ez9qh/)**
- [jQuery.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [jQuery.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 0):

see this example I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/PmNwh/

I use the jquery `next()` function to get the first `.extra-options-tickets`

Answer (score 0):

The `this` element represents the element that invoked the action witch in your case, it's the `<a>` element.

and it seams you want to only show, the next `<div class="extra-options-tickets">` and not all of them, so **you need to think like this**:

In this code, if what fires the `click` is the `<a>` (your selector), how do I go to reach the `<div>` I want to show?

```
<p class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="button" title="Toevoegen"><span>Toevoegen</span></a>
</p>
<div class="extra-options-tickets" style="display: none; ">text</div>
```

From `<a>` you can navigate to the **previous** element, witch is the `<p class="actions">` and the **next** element (the `<div>`) is the one I want...

translating this to code:

```
var extraOptions = $(this) // my <a> element
                     .prev() // previous element (<p class="actions">)
                     .next(); // next element from <p> is <div class="extra-options-tickets">
```

you can always make more generic so you can safely add more elements in between, for example:

instead of calling the `.prev()` (previous element), find the closest elemnt with a class of `actions` and from there, find the next element down the DOM with a class of `extra-options-tickets`, translating:

```
var extraOptions = $(this).closest(".actions").next(".extra-options-tickets");
```